# What does `master..` mean

Tags: git

I'm reading John Wiegley's [Git from the bottom up](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/6-a-commit-by-any-other-name.html). In [A commit by any other name…](https://jwiegley.github.io/git-from-the-bottom-up/1-Repository/6-a-commit-by-any-other-name.html)
he mentioned:

> `name1..name2` — This and the following aliases indicate commit ranges,
> which are supremely useful with commands like log for seeing what’s
> happened during a particular span of time. The syntax to the left
> refers to all the commits reachable from name2 back to, but not
> including, name1. If either `name1` or `name2` is omitted, `HEAD` is used in
> its place.
>
> `master..` — This usage is equivalent to `master..HEAD`. I’m adding it
> here, even though it’s been implied above, because I use this kind of
> alias constantly when reviewing changes made to the current branch.

I'm confused here: `HEAD` shall always be the last commit of `master` right? then what does it mean by `master..HEAD`?

Comment: *`HEAD` shall always be the last commit of `master` right?* No. `HEAD` could be pointing to a commit reachable from another branch (e.g. `dev`) but unreachable from the `master` branch.

Comment: @jub0bs But "`name1..name2` — ... The syntax to the left refers to all the commits reachable from `name2` back to, but not including, `name1`" If `HEAD` points to a commit from branch `dev`, different to and unreachable from `master`, `master..HEAD` doesn't make sense, no?

Comment: `A..B` can be understood as "everything reachable from `B`" MINUS "everything reachable from `A`". Some people picture it more easily like this (it was my case).

Comment: Even if `HEAD` is unreachable from `master` or vice versa, `master..HEAD` still makes sense: Usually, there are older commits that are reachable by both `HEAD` *and* `master`. Then `master..HEAD` excludes those older commits.

Comment: @j6t i'm quite lost at your comments, mind if you elaborate with an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `HEAD` shall always be the last commit of `master` right?

Only if you are currently "on" branch `master`.

Let's be totally concrete with a few examples, so that you can see how this works.  We'll start by creating a new, totally empty Git repository:

```
$ mkdir example && cd example
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo just an example > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) a3de110] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

You will get a different hash ID than I did, and if you set up your Git to create new repositories using a different branch name (e.g., `main`), you will get a different branch name, but either way the:

```
[<some name here> (root-commit) <abbreviated-hash>] initial
```

line tells you several things:

- This is a *root commit*, which in this case is the very first commit in this new repository.  The first commit is kind of special because it is always a root commit (and often is the only root commit).  Root commits aren't particularly interesting.  In a sense, they're particularly *dull*, because they are where all the action *stops*.
- The current branch name is (in my case) `master`.
- The abbreviated hash ID of my new commit was `a3de110`.

The full hash ID of any commit is its "true name": this name works in *every* Git repository and means *that* commit.  Since I just made it in my repository, and you don't have the commit I just made, you don't have this commit, and therefore you don't have this hash ID either.  These hash IDs are universally unique!<sup>1</sup>

Anyway, let's take a look at the *name* `HEAD` right now:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git rev-parse HEAD
a3de1101707189f42f01b50fed47aa350398f49a
```

Here we see that, yes, we're on branch `master`—its full name is `refs/heads/master`—and its full hash ID is that big ugly [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) number.

---

<sup>1</sup>We can prove that this is mathematically impossible (it's obvious from the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)), and since Git depends on this impossibility, we've proven that Git will eventually break.  In practice, however, Git keeps working for decade after decade: the actual chance of breakage is similar to (and almost always actually smaller than) the chance that you'll be hit by lightning and die while you sit at your keyboard and work in your repository.  It's *theoretically* possible, it just doesn't happen often enough in real life to worry about.

---

#### There aren't enough commits to be interesting yet

Since a repository with just one commit is so dull, let's make several more commits.  Let's also make some additional branch names:

```
$ echo one > file1
$ git add file1
$ git commit -m 'add a first file'
[master 0f553c5] add a first file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file1
$ echo two >> file1
$ git add file1 && git commit -m 'add a second line to file1'
[master fbdddac] add a second line to file1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
$ git switch -c b1
Switched to a new branch 'b1'
$ echo two > file2 && git add file2 && git commit -m 'add second file'
[b1 51a610e] add second file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file2
$ git switch master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git switch -c b2
Switched to a new branch 'b2'
$ echo three > file3 && git add file3 && git commit -m 'add different second file'
[b2 e683c47] add different second file
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 file3
```

We now have three branch names (`master`, `b1`, and `b2`) and are currently "on" `b2`:

```
$ git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
* e683c47 (HEAD -> b2) add different second file
| * 51a610e (b1) add second file
|/  
* fbdddac (master) add a second line to file1
* 0f553c5 add a first file
* a3de110 initial
```

This shows how Git draws the graph (see also [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452)), and if we use `git rev-parse` we can see that `HEAD` refers to `b2`, which means the commit whose hash starts with `e683c...`:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
refs/heads/b2
$ git rev-parse HEAD
e683c472999de3d39c3e69d030b362df561b5711
$ git rev-parse b2
e683c472999de3d39c3e69d030b362df561b5711
```

#### Now we have enough stuff to work with

For StackOverflow discussion purposes, I like to draw my graph horizontally instead of vertically.  Git puts the newest commits towards the top; I put them towards the right.  Here's the same graph, except that instead of big ugly hash IDs, I use single letters to stand in for each commit, and draw newer commits towards the right:

```
        D   <-- b1
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        E   <-- b2 (HEAD)
```

The *newest* commit, `add different second file` (`e683c...`), is on the bottom row.  The *branch name* `b2`—that is, `refs/heads/b2`—*points to* this commit, or in other words, `git rev-parse b2` prints out that big ugly hash ID.

The *special* name `HEAD` is currently *attached to* the name `b2`.  So `HEAD` *means* `b2` right now.

If we run:

```
git log master..b2
```

or:

```
git log master..HEAD
```

or:

```
git log master..
```

(all of which *currently* mean the same thing) we'll see commit `e683c...`:

```
$ git log master..
commit e683c472999de3d39c3e69d030b362df561b5711 (HEAD -> b2)
Author: Chris Torek <chris.torek@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Dec 19 01:00:28 2022 -0800

    add different second file
```

And indeed, that's just what we see.  If I *switch back* to `master`:

```
$ git switch master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

that changes the attachment of `HEAD`: it's now attached to `master`, so now `master..HEAD` means the same as `master..master`, which means *no commits*, and that's what we'll see in `git log` output:

```
$ git log master..
$
```

#### Selection with and without history

In most Git commands, the two-dot syntax `A..B` "means":

- starting at commit `B` and working backwards, list out all the commits you can find this way, but then
- starting at commit `A` and working backwards, list out all all the commits you can find *this* way.

We "paint" or "highlight" the first set of commits in green, and then "paint over" (or re-highlight) everything in the second set in red.  The commits that are now highlighted only in green are the ones we've selected.

This works this way for `git log`, `git cherry-pick`, and some other Git commands.  It takes a while to get used to.  For instance, given the graph I have above, what does `b1..b2` mean?  Well, let's look at the graph:

```
        D   <-- b1
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        E   <-- b2
```

(I took `HEAD` out since we're not using it at the moment).  We want to start at `b2`—commit `E`, or `e683c...` in the repository I just made, and highlight that in green.  Then we work backwards: `E` leads backwards to `C`, so we highlight `C` in green, and move back another step to `B` and highlight that in green, and move back to `A` and highlight it green.  Commit `A`, being our root commit, doesn't have any commits before it, so that's where we stop highlighting in green.

Now we highlight commit `D`—commit `51a61...`—in *red*.  We weren't going to list it anyway, but we still "paint it red" for now.  Then we move back one hop, to commit `C`, which is the commit that comes before `D`, and paint that one red.  *This* "red paint" overwrites the earlier "green paint", so now we're *not* going to show commit `C`.  Then we move back another hop to `B` and mark it in red, and so on.

The end result is that we show only commit `E`.  This is the same as `master..b2`.  The reason it shows up the same, even though `master` selects `C` while `b1` selects `D`, is that `C`-and-earlier are the only commits that `git log b2` *would have* selected.  The *de-selection* process de-selects `C`-and-earlier, regardless of whether we start it out at `C` itself, or start it out at `D`.

This gets us into another confusing thing in Git.  The `git log` command works by doing "selection with history".  That is, we run:

```
git log b2
```

and Git uses branch name `b2` to find commit `E` and shows that commit, then works backwards.  This shows us the *entire history* as found by starting at `E` and working backwards.

Some Git commands, `git log` being the most common one you'll use, do just this sort of thing: select *with history*.  That is, you tell the commands "start here" and they do that, but then they *also work backwards* from there.  For these commands, the range syntax `b1..b2` or `stop..start` or whatever *keeps them from working all the way back to the beginning of time*.

Other Git commands, such as `git cherry-pick`, don't do this kind of "select with history".  If you run:

```
git cherry-pick e683c472999de3d39c3e69d030b362df561b5711
```

Git will locate commit `e683c472999de3d39c3e69d030b362df561b5711` (assuming you have my last commit here) and attempt to copy it to a new and supposedly improved commit, since that's what `git cherry-pick` is for.<sup>2</sup>  Cherry-pick, by default, selects *without* history, and using `stop..start` with `git cherry-pick` makes it copy *all the commits* in the range.

So you end up needing to know: *Does this command select **with history** or **without history** by default?*  But it turns out that as you use Git, this eventually "feels natural".  Just experiment a bit the first time you use a new command: make a temporary "junk" clone and see what happens.

---

<sup>2</sup>Once any commit is *made*, it's unchangeable, so if you mean to change stuff other than "where the commit goes in the graph" or "the log message for that commit", you'll probably want `git cherry-pick -n`, which means *copy the work, but don't commit yet*.  Git being what it is, there are workarounds if you screw up here, and the main thing to remember is this: *If you've **committed** something, it's now **in Git** and you can probably get it back as long as you still have the repository; if you have **not committed** it's **not in Git** and Git cannot help you get it back.*  So it tends to be a good idea to make a lot of small commits.

---

#### But `git diff` is weird

One command we use a whole lot in Git is `git diff`, and like `git log`, you can run:

```
git diff A..B
```

The thing about `git diff` is that it *refuses to obey all the normal rules here*.  The two-dot syntax *does not mean* "every commit in the range".  **Instead, `git diff A..B` means exactly the same thing as `git diff A B`.**  The Git authors/maintainers have decided to encourage people to use the second form.  It has another advantage as it's one character shorter.  It does mean you can't use the implied `HEAD`, because:

```
git diff xyzzy
```

means *compare the commit selected by the name `xyzzy` to the current working tree* rather than *compare the commit selected by `xyzzy` to the current commit*.  You have to use:

```
git diff xyzzy HEAD
```

for the latter.  It's a little annoying, really.  It might be nice if `git diff` just rejected the two-dot syntax entirely.

Comment: thank you very much. very detailed and clear explanation. now i get it.